# Presentations of rational numbers into product

Tags: number-theory

**Prove or disprove:**

For every rational number $q$ there exist rational numbers $q_1$, $q_2$, $q_3$ and $q_4$, such that:

- $q_1\times q_2\times q_3\times q_4 = q$
- $q_1+q_2+q_3+q_4 = 0$

**My work so far:**

I was able to solve it for $q_1$, $q_2$, $q_3$, $q_4$ and $q_5$:

- $-q\times\frac{q}{2}\times\frac{q}{2}\times\frac{2}{q}\times\left(-\frac{2}{q}\right)=q$
- $-q+\frac{q}{2}+\frac{q}{2}+\frac{2}{q}+\left(-\frac{2}{q}\right)=0$

Comment: What's $n$?  Your problem appears to involve $q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4$.  Was it meant to have $n$ terms?

Comment: @lulu. For example. If $n=5$. then $q_1=-q,...,q_5=\left( -\frac2q\right)$. 

If $n=4$ - my problem

Comment: What's the source of this question, please?

Comment: If it helps, then I can give you the answer for every $q$ which is also an even natural number.

Comment: @barakmanos If $a,b,c,d$ give $2n$, then $\frac{a}{k},\frac{b}{k},\frac{c}{k},\frac{d}{k}$ give $\frac{2n}{k^4}$. So by taking $n=2^3b^3a,k=2b$ you get $\frac{a}{b}$

Comment: @almagest: That works for $n=4$, I was referring to an answer for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @barakmanos Sorry, I should not have used $a,b$ for different things. Suppose you have rationals $q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4$ which give $2n$. Then using the ones which give $2^4b^3a$, the rationals $\frac{q_1}{2b},\frac{q_2}{2b},\frac{q_3}{2b},\frac{q_4}{2b}$ will give $\frac{a}{b}$. So your solution adapts to give any rational $\frac{a}{b}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a terrible solution (I obtained it by solving some diophantine equations):

$$q_1=\frac{(q-2^{10}\cdot3^{4})^2}{2^7\cdot3^4\cdot(q+2^9\cdot3^4)};$$
$$q_2=-4-\frac{q}{2^7\cdot3^4};$$
$$q_3 = \frac{2^3\cdot3\cdot(q+2^9\cdot3^4)}{q-2^{10}\cdot3^4};$$
$$q_4 = -\frac{2^{11}\cdot3^7\cdot q}{(q-2^{10}\cdot3^4)(q+2^{9}\cdot3^4)},$$

but it is a solution.

If $q = -2^{9}\cdot3^4$ or $q= 2^{10}\cdot3^4$ we shell obtain the decomposution for $\frac{q}{2^{12}\cdot 3^{12}}$ and after this multiplay $q_i$ by $2^{3}\cdot 3^{3}$.

Comment: Wow, I am really impressed!

Comment: If it works then it works. Would you like to show how you found it?

Comment: It is slightly easier to see how this works if you take the four numbers: $-\frac{(x-2)^2}{x+1},(x+1),-\frac{6(x+1)}{x-2},\frac{27x}{(x+1)(x-2)}$. It is obvious that they multiply out to $162x$ and it you put them over a common denominator you find they sum to 0. We have $162=2\cdot3^4$, so if you divide each of the numbers by $6b$ and put $x=8b^3a$ then you get a solution for $\frac{a}{b}$.